# Possible to create a Blackberry portal app to a website?

Tags: blackberry

I have a mobile website special for the blackberry. I would like to create a blackberry application that just displays the mobile website. Like a portal. I need same features as a web browser but accessable as a blackberry desktop icon and downloadable in the blackberry store.

I never created a blackberry application before and i just want to know if this is easily possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Functionality is call Blackberry web-icon. you can create web icon as following sample code.

```
import net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.Browser;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.BrowserSession;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;

public class simpleshortcut extends UiApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args){
  simpleshortcut instance = new simpleshortcut();
  instance.enterEventDispatcher();
}

  public simpleshortcut() {
   BrowserSession site = Browser.getDefaultSession();
   site.displayPage("http://websitelink.com");
   System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try that! Btw i investigated it a little and found this site: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/ Do you have any experience with this? I guess i can make a little more 'native' app with this.

Comment: yes, are you want to developed Blackberry Mobile app right? there are different tools for playbook. This is call Blackberry web-works, there are tools to developed web application for blackberry. you can  download web-works  (https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/download/sdk) also blackberry plugin available for that. more help  (http://keraisureshvblackberry.blogspot.in/2012/02/blackbrry-application-development-tools.html), you can join chat for blackberry http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-and-java